# Rotation of HUD popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So, we are using a third party HUD module.  It has been a little squirrely, and to get it to popup over everything I extended it to show itself using the code

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.view];

However, in landscape mode or upside down the popup appears rotated (or more precisely *not* rotated, always aligned to the device, not the interface).  I'm fairly new at iOS so I'm not sure why this is, but I added some code to compensate

```
    bool go = false;
    float angle = 0.0;

    if (mode == OLM_LandscapeLeft)  // I calculate this further above, it works
    {
        go = true;
        angle = 90;
    }

    [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.view];

    if (go)
    {
        float rads = (angle) / 180 * M_PI;
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, rads);
        self.view.transform = transform;    
    }
```

This appears to have no effect, whether I apply the transform before or after the keyWindow.addSubview.

Is there a correct, or at least effective, way to do this?  And if someone can educate me as to why this kind of addSubView appears to ignore the interface orientation, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using UIDeviceOrientation up there but should be using UIInterfaceOrientation.

You can receive this Information with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
```

and the Makros:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape
UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait
```

that way you don't have to use:

```
OLM_LandscapeLeft // might have a computation bug
```

Comment: I am using UIInterfaceOrientation via statusBarOrientation to compute my variable OLD_LandscapeLeft.  Verified working with breakpoints.  The transform is applied, but my popup view still is presented in device orientation.  Inferring, I'm disheartened if there is not an obvious bug in my code above.  So far not a fan of iOS, behavior too often doesnt make sense.

Comment: are you setting the views frame correctly? stupid question, but slow debug ;-)

Comment: I guess I don't know what that means... so maybe not?  Can you clarify?

Comment: can you read self.view.frame from your view? try 
self.view.frame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].bounds before addSubview:

Comment: So no other ideas?  This is very frustrating.